# Get window handle from taskbar by mouse pos

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, taskbar

Can u tell me, how i can get window handle in taskbar by mouse position?
I'm tryed to use Shell_TrayWnd + ReBarWindow32 + MSTaskListWClass but it's doesn't help me.

Comment: Do you mean a handle to a certain window that's displayed on the taskbar, or a specific notification icon, or something else?

Comment: handle to a certain window that's displayed on the taskbar =)

Comment: Well, there might be one way, but it's not super easy. On [this page](http://rammichael.com/7-taskbar-tweaker), they were able to list everything on there because it "injects a DLL into explorer, which reads it’s internal structures". Apparently, those structures are not undocumented, so they might have some position information, considering I'm able to switch the order of windows from the same application by right clicking and dragging.

Comment: Speaking of the taskbar, which OS are you on? Presumably Vista+?

Comment: What is your ultimate goal? Note that the internal structure of the taskbar changes from one version of Windows to the next, so your program may stop working at any time. Perhaps you would be better off using the accessibility interfaces to access the taskbar programmatically.

Comment: `Perhaps you would be better off using the accessibility interfaces to access the taskbar programmatically.` @RaymondChen, if you mean `ITaskBarList*`, then I don’t see how that would help. Those only seem to provide the ability to modify the Taskbar, not retrieve information from it.

Comment: `What is your ultimate goal?` @RaymondChen, I don’t know the OP’s goal, but mine is to make a program/script that lets me toggle windows between maximized/normal by double-clicking on their Taskbar buttons. I’ve cobbled together an AHK script that more or less does that, but it is a bit “kludgey” because I had to work around being unable to get the handle to the window of the button that was clicked.

Comment: @Synetech I was referring to UIAutomation. if your goal is to automate taskbar actions, then UIAutomation is what you want. (Though that doesn't help you. You aren't trying to automate the taskbar. You are trying to modify the taskbar's default behavior.)

Answer (score 0):

[`WindowFromPoint()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633558%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) should do what you need, although it doesn't retrieve handles to disabled or hidden windows. If you need those too you can use [`ChildWindowFromPoint()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632676%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to find children of the taskbar window.

Comment: On Windows 7, at least, all are contained in a window with the title "Running Applications" and the class "MSTaskListWClass". This window has no children.